# user ability to hide one column only on view

Tags: views

What is the best way to give the user the ability to see or hide one column (only one) on a drupal 7 view?  I want to give them a toggle box to be able to hide and unhide the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here http://siripong-computer-tips.blogspot.com/2011/12/hide-table-column-drupal-view-w-jquery.html

View 3 on drupal 7 produces html like this

```
<table class="views-table cols-4">
  <thead> <tr>
    <th class="views-field views-field-title">Example</th>
    <th class="views-field views-field-body">howto</th>
    <th class="views-field views-field-field-1">dynamically</th>
    <th class="views-field views-field-field-2">show/hide</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd views-row-first views-row-last">
      <td class="views-field views-field-title">table column</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-body">Drupal</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-3">Views</td>
      <td class="views-field views-field-4">jquery</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

go to view edit page
Displays -> Page Details -> Page Settings -> Footer
add the following code

```
Show columns
<form>
<input onclick="toggleVis(this, '.views-field-title')" type="checkbox"> Title
<input onclick="toggleVis(this, '.views-field-body')" type="checkbox"> Body
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleVis(chkbox, col){
    if(chkbox.checked == true) {jQuery(col).show();}
    else {jQuery(col).hide();}
  }
</script>
```

using Jquery to toggle hide the column